# How to handle same code parts in Factory Method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

**I reposted question on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236772/how-to-handle-same-code-parts-in-factory-method) but can not delete this question couse already answer here.**
I have some classes:

```
public abstract class House 
{
   public string Name { set; get;}
   public SomeClass Property1 { set; get;}
   public OtherClass Property2 { set; get;}
}

public class WoodenHouse:House 
{
   public string WoodType { set; get;}
   public int WoodAge { set; get;}
}

public class StoneHouse:House 
{
  public string StoneType { set; get;}
}
```

And trying to create Factory Method pattern for this:

```
abstract class Creator
{
    public abstract HouseInfo Info { get; set; }

    public Creator()
    {
    }

    public abstract House FactoryMethod();
}

class WoodenHouseCreator : Creator
{
    public override HouseInfo Info { get; set; }

    public WoodenHouseCreator(WoodenHouseInfo info)
    {
        Info = info;
    }

    public override House FactoryMethod()
    {
        var info = Info as WoodenHouseInfo;

        var woodenHouse = new WoodenHouse();
        woodenHouse.Name = info.Name;
        woodenHouse.Floors = info.Floors;
        woodenHouse.RoofType = info.RoofType;
        woodenHouse.WoodType = info.WoodType;
        woodenHouse.WoodAge = info.WoodAge;
        return woodenHouse;
    }
}

class StoneHouseCreator : Creator
{
    public override HouseInfo Info { get; set; }

    public StoneHouseCreator(StoneHouseInfo info)
    {
        Info = info;
    }

    public override House FactoryMethod()
    {
        var info = Info as StoneHouseInfo;

        var stoneHouse = new StoneHouse();
        stoneHouse.Name = info.Name;
        stoneHouse.Floors = info.Floors;
        stoneHouse.RoofType = info.RoofType;
        stoneHouse.StoneType = info.StoneType;
        return stoneHouse;
    }
}
```

Here are the classes what contain information to create ahouse:

```
class HouseInfo
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Floors { set; get; }
    public string RoofType { set; get; }
}

class WoodenHouseInfo : HouseInfo
{
    public string WoodType { set; get; }
    public int WoodAge { set; get; }
}

class StoneHouseInfo : HouseInfo
{
    public string StoneType { set; get; }
}
```

And Usage:

```
var houseInfo = new WoodenHouseInfo
{
    Name = "HouseName",
    Floors = 2,
    RoofType = "Triangle",
    WoodType = "Pine",
    WoodAge = 100
};

House house;

if(houseInfo is WoodenHouseInfo)
{
    var creator = new WoodenHouseCreator(houseInfo);
    house = creator.FactoryMethod();
    Console.Write((house as WoodenHouse).WoodAge);
}
```

Full code [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xVc0Hj).

My problem is how to handle code duplication. I mean there is a lot of lines that fills base `House` object properties. How can I write that code only once?
Or I should not to use `Factory Method`?

Comment: There is a lot to comment on here, but not actually anything wrong. I think you'd be better suited to posting this on the code review stack exchange site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dave Got it. Will repost this on `codereview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your factories instantiate the new objects and then fill in all of their properties with the right values. You could split instantiation from property value assignment. Your `StoneHouseCreator` could instantiate a `StoneHouse`, use a `HousePopulator` that populates the values that all objects of type `House` have in common, and then the `StoneHouseCreator` could populate the rest of the values that are exclusive to a `StoneHouse`. That same `HousePopulator` could also be used by your `WoodenHouseCreator`, which would then proceed to populate the `WoodenHouse`-specific properties.

If you want to philosophise about this at a higher level, these are the problems that we run into because of *inheritance*. Factories, that is the logical separation of object use from object creation, are more naturally suited to cases where you use *composition* over *inheritance*. If you are interested more in this, I would recommend reading this excellent [article](https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117) on the topic.